Does cooling a phone in a fridge or freezer damage the battery (lithium-ion battery)?
I saw a fair amount of Reddit and Quora posts on whether cooling a phone in a fridge or freezer damage the lithium-ion battery but they give contradictory answers without any evidence or scientific grounding. Does cooling a phone in a fridge or freezer damage the battery?
Reviving a Li-ion battery in freezer? mentions that freezing a battery is deleterious to the battery. How about just using the fridge instead freezer, or using the freezer without freezing the battery?

Depends on the specific chemistry and electrolytes. Storage down to -20C is not an unusual rating. Actual battery performance there will be terrible, which is why lithium batteries for outdoors use come with self-powered heaters.

This question is similar to: Reviving a Li-ion battery in freezer?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Mithoron thanks, I edited the question accordingly to underline the differences.

Such cooling can damage in long term the phone itself by water condensation and corrosion.
